# Validating Configs according to specified rules

Tags: python, json, validation, configuration, build

So I have a few configuration files (JSONs) which I need to deploy along with my project. I'd like to set them up in a python package, which when built checks against a few basic validation rules (written in python)

If `globalConfig.json` contains `{"rulesToUse":["rule1","rule2"]}`, then
If `ruleSets.json` must contain `{"rule1":"<somerule>", "rule2":"<otherrule"}`

What's the best way to go about this? If I create a regular `validation_cfg.py` file at the same level as my 'setup.py' file, and `import validation_cfg; validation_cfg.validate()` which looks for the Configs (at pre-specified locations) and runs my validation logic. Would this even work? What's the best practice in such cases?

Comment: That's a very general question -- and there are many answers -- some projects use executable python scripts for config; some stick with ini or json files; basically the line between code and config is often blurred. My favourite -- try to code your application so that it starts without config (use sensible defaults), and only user's changes are saved as "config".

Answer (score 0):

JSON has its own schema validation language (which is specified in JSON). And the results of a Google search for "json schema validator python" indicate there are Python implementations of the JSON schema validation language.

Will the JSON schema validation language be sufficient for your needs? Or is there a compelling reason for you to invent your own schema validation language?